# Modificar un archivo csv en python

Tags: python, csv

Tengo un archivo en **.csv** y quiero agregarle un nombre a cada columna sin modificar su contenido.

¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido user94589 a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad.

Answer (score 1):

Primero que nada debes leer el archivo, luego usar el writerow algo asi:
Supogamos en el archivo tengo algo asi:

```
Coca cola   | 1.25
Hamburguesa | 2.50
............|...
```

el codigo seria algo asi:

```
import csv
with open('ejemplo.csv',newline='') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    data = [line for line in r]
with open('ejemplo.csv','w',newline='') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerow(['Producto','Precio'])
    w.writerows(data)
```

Resultado:

```
__________________
PRODUCTO    | PRECIO
__________________
Coca cola   | 1.25
Hamburguesa | 2.50
............|...
__________________
```

Espero te sriva y suerte !!

Comment: Gracias, fue de mucha ayuda!